# If I were to set the value of an an index in an array to null, would it just remove that index from the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem where I'm trying to remove a certain number from an array when a button is clicked(id = "button"). This is my code(my jquery link is in my HTML page):

```
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];


var b = 0;
 var index = 0;
 function number_to_remove(){
 var a = prompt("Enter the number that you want to remove from the array from one to ten");
 return a;
};
 $("#button").click(function(){
  b = number_to_remove()
  index = array.indexOf(b)


};
```

and I'm trying to remove the number that they put in in the array. Would it be possible that setting the value of the array's index to null would delete the whole index(as in not setting the index of the array that the number was in to just an empty string)

```
array[index] = null
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can try in your browser console to get instant results.

Comment: `let arr = [1,2,3]; console.log(arr); arr[1] = null; console.log(arr);` Like aaron I'm unsure as to why you didn't just test this in your browser; is there something about the result you got that left you confused? If so, what result did you get? What confused you?

Answer (score 0):

No, `null` is just a value. The element at the index of interest will still exist, with value of `null`.

To remove one or more elements from an array, use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value to null does not remove its spot in the array. The position in the array will just have its value set to null but it will still exist in memory. If you are looking to remove a value from an array, you would want to use the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).